# Keeping the time stamp when syncing with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to keep the original time stamp of a file when synchronizing with Ubuntu One.  Now Ubuntu One is messing with my time stamps, and I no longer know when I last worked on the file.  Ubuntu One also seem to mess up time stamps on the original source host.

This really is a show stopper, and we are just about to implement Ubuntu One across the many users in the organization.

Answer (score 2):

According to [FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-does-the-last-modified-date-timestamp-change-on-my-files-when-theyre-synced/) of Ubuntu One, you can't, because Ubuntu One does not sync metadata about files.